# Html / CSS : image taking half of the screen

Tags: html, css

I would like to create a webpage with a big image taking half on the screen like this :

[image]

How can i do this with CSS ?

Comment: Can you show your existing attempt?

Comment: Show 50% of the image? Resize the image to 50%? Is it the background image of the body or an image inside a div? can you please show us your existing html?

Comment: Downvote from me, you have not explained anything. As the person said above, is this a `background-image` or a `<img>`? You need to provide some code also, this will help us help you.

Comment: i think you can use frames(html)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try something like this? (2 divs)

```
#leftHalf {
   background: url(bg-1.jpg);
   width: 50%;
   position: absolute;
   left: 0px;
   height: 100%;
}

#rightHalf {

   width: 50%;
   position: absolute;
   right: 0px;
   height: 100%;
}
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

The answer at the top forgot something :

```
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

Since you don't want two image but only one. Final code :

```
#leftHalf {
   background: url(bg-1.jpg);
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   width: 50%;
   position: absolute;
   left: 0px;
   height: 100%;
}
```