# Html / CSS : image slashing half of the screen

Tags: html, css

I would like to create a webpage with a big image slashing the screen like this : [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejAiY.png)

I saw this post [Html / CSS : image taking half of the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22321466/html-css-image-taking-half-of-the-screen) , but i have no idea on how to make it "slash" the screen .
Thanks !

Comment: Well you should give it a go and then share the code of where you got to for stackoverflowers to help. That, and maybe look into `transform: skew...`

Comment: The `clip-path` CSS property creates a clipping region that sets what part of an element should be shown. Parts that are inside the region are shown, while those outside are hidden. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `skew` transform method in order to put it at an oblique angle. You can play with values as per your liking.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body{
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slash {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: black;
  transform: skew(-30deg) scale(2);
  position: absolute;
  left:-20vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="slash"></div>
```